# How to visualize a flowchart for the channels?

Tags: timeline, flowcharts

I'm trying to create a flowchart diagram. It includes the following data:

- Time with interval of 30 minutes
- A group of data for each time interval
- Data flow inside to this group
- Data flow outside from this group

Here is my attempt:
[image]

But I think, it's not ok. User can understand which data comes in and which goes outside but it feels like it's so ordinary and not human readable.
What else can I add or change? 
Should I separate the incoming and outgoing data? 
Here is [the file.](http://www.mediafire.com/?6pdp2go2irk29ok)

Comment: Are you sure that `Data5` belongs to the second interval? It looks like the 1st interval began with 120M, then 18% minus 8% was added and finished with 132M, which is the starting amount of the second interval. If so, then I got a little different representation for your data that may work.

Comment: Well, it is actually a example what they gave to me. It means we have a loss of 8% *until the end of first interval*. That means it is drawn in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the amounts shown in your illustration it looks like the flow of data to outside (red arrows) belong to the intervals previous to where you drew them.

In my attempt, I aligned both flows over and under the main arrow, and added divisions in order to clearly state which elements belongs to each interval, so every interval now has a initial value, flows inside and outside, and a final value which belongs to next interval. If there are more than three intervals (five, ten?) you may want to paint them alternatively with two light colors.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMD1xQ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I got it. The number of intervals can vary. Say 10 intervals. Therefore, painting with light colors might work. Another question is, should I put the arrows on the black line or the grey boxes (as the data flows into or outwards from them)

Comment: I would put the green and red arrows on the black one, depicting that the data flow begins with a initial value. But if you prefer you can put the arrows on the grey box, but be sure to align horizontally the tree boxes and the data label.